# Should lots of issues caused by one thing be asked in multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There is a [question saying that their USB, WiFi and Bluetooth are all broken since the upgrade to 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691059/ubuntu-15-10-no-wifi-bluetooth-usb-sound) from 15.04.

Are these multiple questions (because it's 3 different things), or should it be left as one (because they were all caused by the same thing)?

I'm also predicting that these questions are going to arise more with the 15.10 update - it seems to be causing multiple issues in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very good question.

In this specific case I think each issue should be treated separately.

The second and third issue probably have the same answer (i.e. the kernel upgrade caused the wifi and bluetooth modules to not be loaded as they were compiled for another kernel -> recompile and reconfigure each module) but for them to be addressed properly in my opinion two specific answers are required.

The first issue seems totally unrelated to the second and third one and hence in my opinion is deserveful to be treated separately.

Also notice that splitting has the added benefit of being able to address all of those issues individually in case they show up again in other questions individually due to similar but different (in this case hardware) configurations.

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment, but each question should be unique enough and not just a generic "everything broke, halp?" question.

Answer (score 6):

If you can file 3 separate bugs on launchpad, it's three separate questions.  **:)**

Answer (score 4):

In most cases solutions are different. And it is not possible to fix all that in one answer.

Wifi can be fixed by installing Broadcom drivers. There is an answer for that.

Bluetooth needs firmware. There is another solution for that.

It is unclear what is "USB does not work" and is unclear what is the sound issue.

So it is impossible to answer it in one post.

If the question is split, some of the issues may be resolved and some require additional information.

What makes thing worse is a mainline kernel.

Answer (score 4):

In my personal experience and opinion, it would be best to have 3 different questions. Not only would this help others solve the problem faster, but it would also benefit those who find the question via online search.

If someone has say a Bluetooth problem after upgrading, but Wi-Fi and USB are fine, they would be able to search and find a question related to Bluetooth after upgrading to 15.10. If all 3 questions were lumped into 1 thread, it would be harder for other people to find an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it depends; to put it in medical terms, are you treating the symptoms, or treating the source?

In this case, the three problems don't seem to be entirely related; likely, they have similar, but not the same, sources, all of which were triggered by the update to 15.10. So in this case, it would probably be better to have them as one question, then, once solved, post new versions of the question, separated into each specific issue, so as to offer as much efficiency as possible in terms of solution searching. That way, if someone searches for the individual problem, they'll find the individual question, with an answer, and if they search for all three, they'll find the original, compiled question. Smiles all around.

Comment: Hmm that means 3 answers that could go out of date and need maintaining

Comment: @Tim Good point... Although if they linked to each other, then that might solve that problem. And besides, whenever an answer becomes outdated, someone usually posts a more up-to-date question, which could just follow the same pattern.